# Looping through form array inside form group angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular-forms

I get list of data from server and i want to show them inside a **list of spans** as below:

[image]

Each row correspond to one item of list and note that I create this list with `*ngFor` as below:

```js
this.myForm = this.fb.group({
            person: this.fb.array([
                this.fb.group({
                    name: [''],
                    address: ['']
                })
            ])
        })
```

```html
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
      <div formArrayName="person" *ngFor="let person of serverData; let personIndex = index">
          <div [formGroupName]="personIndex">
              <input formControlName="name"/>
              <input formControlName="address"/>
          </div>
      </div>
</form>
```

After running this code the browser gives me this:

**Error:**

> No value accessor for form control with path: 'person -> 0 -> name'

But I know that I should use `myForm.controls.person.controls` instead of `serverData` in for loop, but I want to have ***both*** list and controls together.

Should I use two for loops that one of them iterates over server data and the other one iterates over form controls or I should use another way?

Comment: You can't set formcontrolnames on a span. Why would you even need a form for this if you just show on spans?

Comment: This is a sample that similar to my real code. In reality there is an input with type:'hidden' near these spans @AJT82

Comment: then set the formcontrolnames only on those input fields?

Comment: Ok. Imagine that there are two inputs instead of these spans. Would you please help me?

Comment: Yes I will help, please just provide a [mcve] I don't know where these inputs are. As to your comment, if you just replace the spans with input, your code will work.

Comment: I updated my code above. You are right, this code is working but in the case of creating a list of inputs but when i log the value of person array it just return me the first item of array not the whole array. In general i want to create list of inputs in for loop and i want to be able to access each inputs value dynamically @AJT82

Comment: could you please provide a [mcve], best would be a stackblitz. It's still unclear to me what you are really trying to do, and it's impossible to help if not seeing all code that is needed.

Comment: here you are https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zjtv1w @AJT82

Comment: forms don't work that way, you need to actually push formgroups to your array, so therefore I don't actually see why you would want to iterate `serverData`, since you have to push form groups to the array, so you could as well iterate the formarray instead. Here though I iterate `serverData`, but as mentioned, it really doesn't make sense, since you could iterate the formarray instead. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eokmnn?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Thank you. this solves my problem. @AJT82
How can i mark this answer as a solution of this question?

Comment: You can't accept comments as answer. I've could have written an answer, but I see you already did :) So you can accept it yourself.

Comment: I've deleted it now. write the answer please and then i accept it. thanks @AJT82

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must push all objects from `serverData` to your formarray, so that the array lengths are the same as the `serverData` array. Your template stays as it currently is, but in component, map the values from `serverData` and push the objects with the properties you want to the formarray:

```ts
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.myForm = this.fb.group({
    persons: this.fb.array([])
  });
  this.data();
}

get person() {
  return this.myForm.get("persons") as FormArray;
}

private data() {
  this.serverData = [
    {
      name: "1",
      desc: "one"
    },
    {
      name: "2",
      desc: "two"
    },
    {
      name: "3",
      desc: "three"
    }
  ];

  this.serverData.map(d =>
    this.person.push(this.fb.group({ name: d.name, address: d.desc }))
  );
}
```

**DEMO: [STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eokmnn?file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

Answer (score 1):

NOTE: I like the loop is n the div of fromGroupName

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
      <div formArrayName="person"> >
          <div *ngFor="let person of serverData; let personIndex = index"
               [formGroupName]="personIndex">
              <span formControlName="name">{{person.name}}</span>
              <span formControlName="address">{{person.address}}</span>
          </div>
      </div>
</form>
```

If you iterate over myForm.controls.person.controls, always formGroupName has value, if you has an array and declare BEFORE create the form, At very first state of the application, the FormArray is not created

Comment: As i shown in my question i do not use 'myForm.controls.person.controls'. Now i set values in ngAfterViewInit() as you said that i do not declare array before create form. But still do not working.@Eliseo